# Editing strings with java methods

Tags: java

I am currently studying methods in java, I have used methods to work with arrays but I am having trouble using them with strings.

One of the problems I have is given a string, and a number. I have to print charAt(0) of the string, then every int of the string after.

For example, "Programming" and the number 3 would yield "Pgmn"

If I was to do this without methods I could. But I am not sure how to construct it with a method.

Comment: Please show sample code of how you'd do it without methods.

Comment: Hint: the variables that represent "Programming" and "3" will be your parameters, and your return value will be the variable where you get the "Pgmn" in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate using different jumps from `1`. For example:

```
public void printCharsWithJumps(String s, int jump){
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i += jump){ // adding jump to i each time
        System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
    }       
}
```

Note that I am adding `3` to the loop variable `i` each time, instead of the usual `i++`, which simply increments `i` by 1.

Answer (score 2):

In the solution below, `str` is a **parameter to the method** which will contain the `String` in question.

`x` is an `int` which represents the 'number' in question i.e. we'll print every x*th* character starting from the second character.

The **call** to this method will be made like this:

```
printDesiredCharacters("Programming", 3);



 void printDesiredCharacters(String str, int x)
{
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    System.out.print(arr[0]); //Print first character
    for(int index = x; index < arr.length; index += x)
    {
        System.out.print(arr[index]);//Print every character that is x spaces from the first.
    }
}
```

**Output:**
Pgmn